# Sharepoint - Update Values in a multi-value Lookup from a workflow attached to another list

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, lookup, multivalue

I have three lists: Languages, Files, Components. Components has a Multi-Value Lookup column to Languages. Files contains translation files associated with components in the Components list. When a new translation file is received via email, a workflow fires. The language name gets pulled from the file name and is used in an HTTP GET to assign the id from the Language list and pull the Language title into the File list. Here is the rub. I need to update the Components list Language lookup column with that Id/language.

My first attempt is to use Update Item in the workflow, where I say Update Language in Components with a value of 42 where Id = the component Id. This is giving me an unhandled exception. (I understand that multiple values need to be separated with #;)

So, I tried the HTTP put route. Though, Merge would be more appropriate here. The documentation says it is supported. it is not available in the Call Http web service Dialogue. I have not been successful yet.

Does any one know why my first method would not work? If it is just not possible, then can anyone point me to a good reference for using Put or Merge in SPD?